# differential equation first order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Tried unsuccessfully solving this equation:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{1}{t+2x}$$

I believe there's a substitution that allow solving it, couldn't find it

any help?

Comment: u=t+2x is waving frantically at me!

Answer (score 1):

We have,

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac 1{t+2x}$$

Reciprocating both sides,

\begin{align}\frac{dt}{dx}&=t+2x\\
\frac{dt}{dx}-t&=2x\end{align}

Find integrating factor then solve.